# Filtering for recurring events happening [Today]

Tags: 2007, list-view, filter

Is this possible? Ryan Wheeler says its not [here](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/03/24/filter-by-events-this-week-in-a-sharepoint-calendar/). Tim says it is if your view is of type "Standard View, with expanded recurring events" [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/10/09/filtering-sharepoint-calendar-by-start-time.aspx). I haven't been able to get Tim's suggestion to work. (MOSS 2007)

Comment: Surely someone has tried this before? Is there any information I can add to my question to make it easier to answer / more interesting?

Comment: You questioning me? I mean dare you Question ME? The cheek of it! ;)

Comment: Its a bit like ouija, I'm trying to summon the gods of SharePoint to my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer "No" so we can mark this question as answered.

Obviously if someone knows different...