# Recommendations for a 3rd party webpart that allows recurring events to be filtered by date

Tags: 2007, web-part

A while back I [asked](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13037/filtering-for-recurring-events-happening-today/14555#14555) if it was possible to filter a calendar containing both recurring and normal events for items occurring [Today]. The consensus was **no** which I passed back to the user. Now they've decided the functionality is essential and they're willing to pay for it. Can anyone recommend a 3rd party webpart (MOSS 2007) that will give me something that looks like a standard filter view on a calendar list and handles recurring events? Extra points for something that does aggregation across several lists, but this is secondary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do provide the Lightning Conductor as a cross site collection/cross web application rollup tool. It will aggregate Calendars and display the results within a calendar view. We unfortunately do not display the re-occuring event as we simply aggregate the list item itself. You can signal to your users that it is a recurring event by displaying the Recurrence column. You can filter the results using the [Today] keyword.

If you upgrade to SharePoint 2010 in the future, there is Calendar Overlays. Calendar Overlays allow you to aggregate upto 10 Calendars within one calendar display but within the current site collection.

If you get intouch with us directly at Lightning Tools I would be happy to help explore the possibility of customizing our product to include this feature.

I hope this helps

Brett

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at Lightning Tools [Lightning Conductor](http://www.lightningtools.com/pages/lightning-conductor-web-part.aspx) web part.  I don't recall how it handles recurring events, but I can point them to this thread to see if it does.  Bamboo offers a similar product.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a few clients who have really liked the [Calendar Web Part from Bamboo Solutions](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-calendar-plus-web-part.aspx). I haven't checked that particular filter option, but I have a feeling it will do it. It does aggregate over several lists.